# Use 'top' to view memory usage of a process

Tags: memory, command-line, system, pid

My programme is named 'berkut'. I want to get the CPU and memory usage of this programme, so I use 'top' command together with 'pidof' like following:

```
[root#]pidof berkut
xxx

[root#]top -p xxx
(top screen is shown here)
```

Is there a shortcut way to combine these 2 commands so that I can call it directly with the system call: **system("...");** of C++?

It doesn't matter how long the string passed into 'system' call, but should not be extremely long. I manually run the programme, so I'm quite sure that there is only 1 PID for it. This means when calling 'pidof', the 'xxx' is the only 1 PID found.

Comment: wow! it works! and simple! tks @VictorHugo pls add it as answer

Comment: Added as an answer. I'm glad it worked :D

Comment: or ``top -p `pidof berkut` ``

Comment: i seems without the $(...), all fail with error 'bad pid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
top -p $(pidof berkut)
```

The expression `$(<command>)` tells `bash` to evaluate `<command>` first. It is the same of using `` `<command>` `` as pointed by [@tozka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303277/tozka).

Comment: oh, yes, use the accents, not the apostrophes

Comment: @PaulDinh - If you are working with different OS, using `\`<command>\`` is better because not every shell recognizes `$(<cmd>)` syntax. Otherwise, I recommend the last because it is easier to see and maintain.